# Power of expectation of a random variable

Tags: inequality, expected-value

Let X be a nonnegative random variable. Prove that $$E(X)\le[E(X^2)]^\frac12\le[E(X^3)]^\frac13\le...$$
I have proved that $E(X)\le[E(X^2)]^\frac12$ using Cauchy inequality, but I can't prove the rest.

Comment: Use Jensen's inequality to prove $E(X)\leqslant(E(X^a))^{\frac1a}$ for any $a>1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Answer (score 1):

Apply Jensen's inequality, when $n\gt1$, $\varphi(x)=x^n$ is a convex function, so $\varphi[E(X)] \ge E[\varphi(X)]$.
$$[E(X)]^2 \ge E(X^2)$$
$$E(X) \ge [E(X^2)]^\frac 12$$
Let $Y=X^2$
$$[E(Y)]^\frac 32 \ge E(X^\frac 32)$$
$$[E(X^2)]^\frac 12 \ge [E(X^3)]^\frac 13$$
And so on, $$E(X)\le[E(X^2)]^\frac12\le[E(X^3)]^\frac13\le...$$